# How do I make an object cast shadows but be invisible in the render?

Tags: rendering, light

I want an object to affect light (cast shadows) but I don't want it to be visible in the image. There should be a way to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Which rendering engine and Blender version are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Cycles or Eevee, that can be:

[image]

It uses the light path, testing if it is a ray from the object to the camera: if yes, the transparent shader is used.

For Eevee, you need to set the blend mode to alpha blend:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes you may be right... I propose you add another answer. That could interest people anyway. As you wish.

Answer (score 9):

@Lemon's answer makes the object invisible to the camera, but still visible to shadows.

It also leaves the object visible to all other influences it might have on the scene .. in 
glossy and diffuse reflections, if seen through refractive objects, and so forth. That may be what you want.

But if you want the shaded object to be invisible to *everything* but shadows, this is an alternative arrangement:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robin! This works perfect. I should note that in EEVEE, depending on the distance of the light source(s) to the object you are trying to occlude with your shadow caster, having "Soft Shadows" enabled may prevent the shadow caster from providing 100% shadow coverage.

Comment: Interestingly, this still works even without the light path node, just by plugging the transparent shader directly into the Material Output (providing the material Blend Mode is set to Alpha Blend and Shadow Mode is set to Opaque). However, the node setup you included is the superior method, since it guarantees compatibility when switching between Cycles and EEVEE.

Comment: @Copperplate Ah! So you can make use of EEVEE's shadow-mapping mech.. Okydoky.. that's handy!

Comment: One final note: to control shadow intensity (make shadows lighter or "semi-opaque"), such as the shadow cast from an illuminated lampshade, simply insert a math node between the shadow ray output and the Mix Shader's fac input in the node setup above. Set it to "Multiply", and adjust the math node's value input to be any positive number less than 1 (ie. for half strength shadows, set to 0.5). This technique works great in both Cycles and EEVEE, but to work in EEVEE, you must set the Shadow Mode to "Alpha Hashed".

Comment: @Copperplate feel free to improve this answer, if you like, or add one of your own? This looks like a useful addition to the archive.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest of them all would be a single glass BSDF shader with an IOR of 1. Does the job 100%